# How absolute is NIP in a model?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

The following question is motivated by a model theoretic question but doesn't really involve any model theory per se. That said, I don't know the appropriate keywords for the relevant functional analysis, so I opted for the current title in the interest of getting someone with relevant knowledge to look at the question. If anyone has a suggestion for a more appropriate title, please let me know.

In their paper [*Remarks on NIP in a model*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04674), Khanaki and Pillay provide a special case of [a result of Bourgain, Fremlin, and Talagrand](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373913). Here is the stated result:

> (BFT Theorem) Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $A$ be a uniformly bounded subset of $C(X)$, where $C(X)$ is the space of continuous real valued functions $X$. The following are equivalent.
>
> - For any reals $r<s$ and sequence $\{f_i\}_{i<\omega}$ of elements of $A$, there is an $I \subseteq \omega$ such that no $x \in X$ satisfies $f_i(x) \leq r$ for all $i \in I$ and $f_i(x) \geq s$ for all $i \notin I$.
> - $A$ is relatively sequentially compact in $\mathbb{R}^X$ (i.e. every sequence of elements of $A$ has a convergent subsequence).
>
> If $A$ is countable, then these are also equivalent to the following.
>
> - Any $f \in \mathbb{R}^X$ in the closure of $A$ is a Borel (measurable) function (where the closure is taken in the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^X$, i.e. the topology of pointwise convergence).
> - Each $f \in \mathbb{R}^X$ in the closure of $A$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence from $A$.
> - The closure of $A$ has cardinality strictly less than $2^{2^\omega}$.

I'm curious about how this result interacts with forcing, specifically passing to a forcing extension in which $A$ is countable. To narrow it down to specific questions, I'll ask these:

> **Question 1:** Does there exist a compact Hausdorff space $X$, an uncountable $A \subseteq C(X)$ satisfying the conditions of the BFT theorem, and a forcing extension $V[G]$ in which $A$ is countable, such that $A$ no longer satisfies the conditions of the BFT theorem in $V[G]$?

> **Question 2:** For any compact Hausdorff space $X$ and uncountable $A \subseteq C(X)$ satisfying the conditions of the BFT theorem, does there exist a forcing extension $V[G]$ in which $A$ is countable and still satisfies the conditions of the BFT theorem?

I need to be slightly careful with what I mean by this because, of course, $X$ will possibly fail to be compact in $V[G]$. For any compact Hausdorff space $X$ and forcing extension $V[G]$, there is a compact Hausdorff space $X' \in V[G]$, unique up to homeomorphism, such that $C(X)^V$ is dense in $C(X')^{V[G]}$ in the uniform norm. (One way to construct this is to take the closure in $V[G]$ of $X$ embedded as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{C(X)}$ in the obvious way.) Every $f \in C(X)^V$ extends to a unique continuous function on $X'$. So when I say that $A$ does not satisfy the conditions of the BFT theorem in $V[G]$, I mean that the set of these canonical extensions to $X'$ does not satisfy the conditions of the BFT theorem.

This is a natural way to 'complete' a compact Hausdorff space in a forcing extension, but it's also relevant to the specific context of model theory because it's how type spaces behave, which is to say $(S_n(A)^V)'$ is precisely $S_n(A)^{V[G]}$.